# iFrame padding not same as source

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, doctype

I've created a small javascript Rich Text Editor, but when I open it in an iframe, the padding of certain objects are not correct. Here's an image of what it looks like from the source:
[image: correct padding from source]

But, when I put it in the iframe and use this source, it looks like this:

[image: incorrect padding from iframe]

I tried changing the `DOCTYPE` and changing the `margin:` and `padding:` to `0px`, but nothing changed. I can't seem to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug and checking the source of the styling for the incorrectly rendering elements?

Comment: what I can see is, the iframe width is not enough, making the Grey-bit 16,32,64 falls down to another row. This may cause the problem. Try add more width to the iframe

Comment: Ugh! @ShivanRaptor, That was what it was. Is there a way to allow overflow from the iframe? I've tried setting the `offset` of the colorpicker, but it doesn't seem to work until the 2nd or 3rd click. Notice that the offset is incorrect in the second picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I figured out what I needed to do. I had the colorpicker `div` set to be at a specific `.offset()` with jQuery, but it didn't fully function in the iframe. The reason was because the `div`'s width was variant on the color bit function. Because of this, jQuery had trouble determining the left positioning of the colorpicker `div` since the offset function I wrote uses the width of the `div`. So, all I needed to do was set the width of the colorpicker. ;) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, what's happening is that the iframe's width is not enough. From the source the colorpicker box can fill all the space it needs, but in the iframe it's cramped, shrinking everything inside it and making the color bands at the end and the gray 16, 32, 64 fall to another row. Also, the offset for the colorpicker seems to be off; are you using percentage-widths and offsets, maybe? You can do many things to solve this: just increase the width of the iframe (you can't make the box only spill out of the iframe), move the colorpicker box to the left, make the picker's size fixed (you'll need to resize the iframe or make it scrolling for this, etc. It's probably not a DOCTYPE problem, though. More details would be appreciated, but I hope this helps!